# Upper bound on the norm of the inverse of an eigenvectors basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix s.t. every entry in $A$ is either $0$ or polynomially-bounded. That is, there exists a constant $c$ for which $n^{-c }\le A[i,j] \le n^{c}$.

Let $A = VJV^{-1}$ be a Jordan decomposition where the columns of $V$ have norm $1$. I am interested in upper-bounding $\|V^{-1}\|$, even very crudely (say, at most $n^{n^{d}}$ for some constant $d$).

I trying going through $\mathrm{det}(V^{T}V)$,
for which an upper bound is easy, but could not come up with a lower bound.

Comment: You can multiply every element of $V$ by some scalar $c$ and every element of $V^{-1}$ by $\frac 1c$ giving you the freedom to make $\|V^{-1}\|$ equal whatever you need it to be.

Comment: Right, but I am interested in the case where the columns of $V$ have unit norm (I updated the question). In fact, as even that way $V$ is not unique, I am interested in the "best" Jordan decomposition in that sense.

Comment: You might be able to come up with an upper bound that depends on the spacing of the eigenvalues.  If your have close or repeated eigenvalues, I have a hunch that this won't work.